# TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null while displaying street view panorama using vue js

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js, vuejs2, google-street-view

I'm trying to display street view panorama using google maps API in VueJS
I followed Google maps doc https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-simple?hl=fr, this is the template section:

```
 <div id="map"></div>
 <div id="pano"></div>
```

and this is the script section:

```
mounted() {
var fenway = { lat: 42.345573, lng: -71.098326 };
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(42.345573, -71.098326);
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  center: latlng,
  zoom: 14
});


var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
  document.getElementById("pano"),
  {
    position: fenway,
    pov: {
      heading: 34,
      pitch: 10
    }
  }
);
map.setStreetView(panorama);
}
```

I mentionned this in index.html

```
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY"> 
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem, so I loaded the script in main.js

```
export const loadedGoogleMapsAPI = new Promise( (resolve,reject) => {

window['initialize'] = resolve;

let GMap = document.createElement('script');

GMap.setAttribute('src',
'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/jskey=API_KEY&callback=initialize');
document.body.appendChild(GMap); 
 });
```

Then I imported it in my component:

```
import { loadedGoogleMapsAPI } from "@/main";
```

then I called initialize function in mounted():

```
  mounted() {
loadedGoogleMapsAPI.then(() => {
  console.log("loaded");
  this.initMap();
});
},
methods: {
initMap() {
  const element = document.getElementById(this.mapName);
  console.log(this.mapName);
  const options = {
    zoom: 14,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(this.station.lat, this.station.lng)
  };
  const map = new google.maps.Map(element, options);
  var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
        document.getElementById(this.panoName), {
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(this.station.lat, 
          this.station.lng),
          pov: {
            heading: 34,
            pitch: 10
          }
        });
    map.setStreetView(panorama);
  }
  }
```

I hope this will be useful for you